# Android apk version code and version name resets after signing

Tags: android, android-manifest

I update my android manifest file with progressively increased version code and sign it with the store keys. After the signing, the version code is reset to previous value. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem recently ...u might be changing the versionCode in bin/manifest make sure its the main manifest.

And Check this hope it might help you....

[Can't update VersionCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781912/cant-update-versioncode)