# Can't update VersionCode

Tags: android, android-manifest, publish, publishing

I have published an app on Google Play 15 days ago, I made some modifications to the app and now I want to publish it again .

When I tried to upload the apk without changing the VersionCode="1" the Google Developers Console gave me an Error: App with versionCode="1" already exist.

Then I tried to change the version code to 2 and export the apk, unfortunately the VersionCode reverts back to "1" always.

Please help out with this issue.

Comment: are you sure you're updating the versionCode, not the versionName ?

Comment: Make sure you are editing the manifest, and not the Bin/manifest

Comment: @Doomsknight ...ya i might have tried using the bin/manifest,i used the main manifest now it solved my issue..!!
Thanks everyone !

Comment: @manoj Good to hear! It came to mind from past experience :p I've added an answer to help others. Please accept. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are **NOT** using the `bin/manifest` as this is the built one, and will constantly be changed on build/export.

Use the proper `manifest` which can be found in the root directory of the project.

I too did this for a while by accidently opening the bin folder and was baffled.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I have changed 3 versions untill was done. There are many possibilities.
You didn't type the key (password) correctly, Second try to Deactivate the first version then upload the new version. Try not to forget to change Version Code and Version name, and Export APK as first time.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem even when editing the proper manifest file (not bin/manifest) usually when editing a project from different machines.

In Eclipse, try "cleaning" the project and re-building. Should update the APK with the proper versions on your next install.

Comment: Yup, in 6 years of Android dev I've never seen it garble up the version info of an APK, but today was the day and a clean was the only fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle to build you must change it on build.gradle: 
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xx.sadsa"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're in Android Studio:
`Build` > `Generate Signed APK...`

Answer (score 0):

None of Above does not work in my case. Go to File->Invalidate Cache/Restart work for me

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to upload the apk to google play console (Note: I have updated the version name and version code in build.gradle) after lot of searching in my case just cleaning of the project was good enough and I was able to upload the apk to console.